# Problems with copying file to System32 folder through a jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler

I was trying to copy a .dll file from "C:\Tests" to "C:\Windows\System32"
by COPY command like
 COPY "C:\Tests\windows\test.dll" "C:\Windows\System32\test.dll"

Jenkin job output says file copied and I tried printing and checking for existence of file in the same job and everything works.

But After the job completes , when I check for the file in the system32 , file doesn't exists.

What can be the issue ?? Is it any cleanup settings of jenkins ? or some permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

When Jenkins executes something on the filesystem, that happens on the **master** or **slave** node's filesystem, not the filesystem of the user who is browing/triggering the job.

Are you sure your are checking for the existence of the file on the **same node** that the job ran on?

Comment: Yes . I am restricting the job to be run only on my slave machine and I am checking in the same system

Comment: A few things to be noted:
I'm also performing a copy in another folder (this happens neatly).
Furthermore i can print the contents of the file in the current job, do a wait and print the contents again, however between the two prints when i check the slave the file in the system32 dir is missing while the file  exists in the  other location

Comment: Do this test: after last successful run of the job (where you can print the content in-job), change the job configuration to print the content of system32 file **before** the copy command. If the file persisted there from the last run, it would be able to print at the very beginning of this run

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
I got the solution as it was copying to syswow64. It's a windows feature to redirect to syswow64 dy default when running from a 32 bit cmd. and by default system launches the 32 bit cmd